# Unable to view Images on converting a python script to .exe format

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe

I tried to convert my python script to a windows execute format (.exe), but the images don't show up on the icons. I have posted the two pictures.

My setup file has the code to process images

```
data=[('imageformats',[r'C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg4.dll',
    r'C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\qgif4.dll',
    r'C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\qico4.dll',
    r'C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\qmng4.dll',
    r'C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\qsvg4.dll',
    r'C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\qtiff4.dll'
    ])]
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Please help us reproduce your problem. Unless this is a known issue, nobody knows what your code does. Please review [these recommendations](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part about reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. It was related to the path of the images in the code. the program was not able to locate the images outside the parent folder. 
the solution is to give the path of the images in the following format.
QtGui.QIcon(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'images'(Folder), 'actions'
(Subfolder), 'button-rotate-cw.png'(Name of the image)))